Create A Custom Drawable
i create this for qr code scanner and i need to set transparent part of square so it view proper show
currently red color is apply but i need exclude red color from center square.
inner square is set transparent.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/overlay_transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="@dimen/margin_250dp"
        android:height="@dimen/margin_250dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="4dp"

                android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="12dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>


